# Where to put the Database related code in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a following piece of code which connects to database and executes a query, I have a no clarity in placing of this code(Model/Service).

```
def value
def url      = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.url
def username = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.username
def password = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.password
def driver   = ConfigurationHolder.config.dataSource.driverClassName
def sql      = Sql.newInstance(url, username, password, driver)

sql.eachRow("select field_value from application_configuration where field_name=?", [field]) {
        value=it.field_value
}
```

I have a class called ApplicationConfiguaration, I am querying on this domain.

I have two doubts

1) where to put the Database connection logic
2) where to put the query execution logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't created a domain object to represent `application_configuration`, you should consider that, and use [domain object finders](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders) or [HQL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#hql).

If you need to perform the query outside of GORM, it should probably go in a service.  Note that a DataSource object can be automatically injected into your service and that a Sql object can be created directly from it.  You could have something like this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class ApplicationConfigurationService {
    def dataSource

    def valueForName(name) {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

        sql.eachRow(...) {
            value=it.field_value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The query execution goes on the Service side.

The view interacts with the Controller, this one with the Service and the last one with the data of DB mapping it to the defined Model objects.

The Database connection login goes on DataSource.groovy con /Conf

```
DataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache=true
cache.use_query_cache=true
cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
        username=""
        password=""
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
        username=""
        password=""

    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Also there's no need to execute using the Groovy SQL object, you can interact with your domain object directly e.g. `ApplicationConfiguaration.list { eq "fieldName", value }`